# Windows automatically closes my ports

Tags: remote-desktop, port-forwarding, windows-11

***The problem***
I want to be able to remotely access a VM on my PC with Windows Remote Desktop (no other remote desktop client can be used for reasons which I won't explain right now), but the problem is, after a short time of inactivity, my port 3389 closes, which I port-forwarded successfully. My questions:

1. Is this normal behavior?
2. Is there a way to make it open 24/7?
3. Is it a problem with my router?

Any feedback would be appreciated, but just don't post "Oh no that is not secure use something else blah blah blah" because I am unable to for some specific reasons

Comment: Are you sure the Guest in the VM is not closing the port? Do other services inside the VM remain active?

Comment: In the RDP server, run `gpedit.msc`, position to *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Session Time Limits*, check if some policy is configured badly - by default all are Not configured.